# Does cloudbees RUN@cloud bill by the hour or by the minute?

Tags: cloudbees, paas

For example, if I am running an app and it scales out to 5 servers for just 10 minutes, do I pay for 5 servers for 10 minutes or 5 for the whole hour?

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees measures your app multiple times per hour, and bills by the minutes consumed. This is also true of DEV@cloud (so the resolution of measurement is by the minute).